# Enable UV Editor Sync Selection always on

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Is there a preference or other way to have the UV Editor's 'UV Sync Selection' always on by default.  It's slightly annoying to have to turn it on every time when I mostly always want it on. Not a big deal really but falls into the "it would be nice" category

Answer (score 2):

Start Blender with a default scene. Switch to the <kbd>UV Editing</kbd> layout and enable <kbd>Sync Selection</kbd>. Then switch back to the normal <kbd>Layout</kbd> view and select <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Defaults</kbd> > <kbd>Save  Startup File</kbd>. This will only work with a new file. If you load an existing file it will pick up whatever setting was saved with that file unless you uncheck <kbd>Load UI</kbd> on the <kbd>N</kbd> panel in the file selector when loading.